# widget (NCWidgetProviding class) can interact with open App iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I want to develop a widget for iOS.
The situation is:
- app open and calculate some "X" data every second.
Behaviour:

- widget read "X" data updated and display it.

Widget and iOS app are two separated world?

Thank you

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do then, is essentially pass the calculated data from your main app to your widget. Simple, just use AppGroups and NSUserDefaults to share the data you need with your widget like so:

Calculate your data and then save it to NSUserDefaults in your app like so:

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
[shared setObject:object forKey:@"yourkey"];
[shared synchronize];
```

To read the data from the NSUserDefaults in your widget, do the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *shared = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.yougroup"];
id value = [shared valueForKey:@"yourkey"];
```

You will also need to setup AppGroups in your app and Widget before they can access the same data, follow this guide to do that: http://tapadoo.com/2014/sharing-nsuserdefaults-between-your-app-and-a-today-extension-on-ios-8/